# How to tell if an accordian item is visible or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using two ul lists to create a collapsible menu style list. Here is an example:

```
<ul class="element_list element_group ui-sortable">
    <li id="de_1" class="element_config_form element_group_parent eg-collapsed" style="height: 1em;"></li>
    <li id="de_2" class="element_config_form element_group_parent eg-collapsed" style="height: 1em;"></li>
    <li id="de_57" class="element_config_form element_group_parent eg-collapsed" style="height: 1em;"></li>
    <li id="de_47" class="element_config_form element_group_parent eg-collapsed" style="height: 1em;"></li>
    <li id="de_3" class="element_config_form element_group_parent eg-collapsed" style="height: 1em;"></li>
    <li id="de_4" class="element_config_form element_group_parent eg-collapsed" style="height: 1em;"></li>
    <li id="de_18" class="element_config_form element_group_parent eg-collapsed" style="height: 1em;"></li>
    <li id="de_20" class="element_config_form element_group_parent eg-collapsed" style="height: 1em;"></li>
    <li id="de_49" class="element_config_form element_group_parent eg-expanded" style="height: auto;">
        <div></div>
        <ul class="element_group">
            <li id="de_51" class="element_config_form element_group_leaf"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the example the last element is expanded, however the other `<li>` elements have sub-items as well.

I am using the jQuery sortable API to move these elements around but I am getting some funky behaviour (a lot of items jumping back and forth with dragging the mouse to place the element). I believe that I am getting this behaviour because the dragged element is checking whether it is intersecting with every list element, even the hidden ones.

My question is, how to only check intersection with only the visible elements? The css only uses `overflow: hidden` to hide the unseen elements.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: If you provide a Fiddle we'll be better tooled to help you.

Comment: I will try to put one together, but the code I am using is rather complicated so I am not sure I can reduce it to something simpler in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see how wide an element is by using the jQuery `.width()` or `.height` function, which would check if overflow is going to be activated or not.

Here is the documentation with examples of implementation: http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: Can you show with an example how you can determine if overflow is going to be active or not by using the height function. I am not following.

Comment: @user5013 Examples are provided in this answer/post, simply visit the documentation link provided. If you have a specific question perhaps another thread is more appropriate. If the explanation and examples bring resolution to your issue please mark this post as the answer so as to expedite resolution for other users in the StackOverflow community